# Override widget 's paint event within MainWindow

Tags: qt, events, paintevent

I have a widget container I wish to manually paint.
However, it is located within my GUI's MainWindow class.

Is there any way I can register on the paint event for a specific QWidget, so my own function will be called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for eventFilter. It will help you

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to override the [paintEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#paintEvent) on the widget
you would like to draw in a custom subclass, and then use that class in your GUI.